# How to check uploaded file type in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I used this code to check for the type of images,

```
$f_type=$_FILES['fupload']['type'];

if ($f_type== "image/gif" OR $f_type== "image/png" OR $f_type== "image/jpeg" OR $f_type== "image/JPEG" OR $f_type== "image/PNG" OR $f_type== "image/GIF")
{
    $error=False;
}
else
{
    $error=True;
}
```

but some users complain they get an error while uploading any type of images, while some others don't get any errors!

I was wondering if this fixes the problem:

`if (mime_content_type($_FILES['fupload']['type']) == "image/gif"){...`

Any comments?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Never use `$_FILES..['type']`. The information contained in it is not verified at all, it's a user-defined value. Test the type yourself. For images, [`exif_imagetype`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) is usually a good choice:

```
$allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
$detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']);
$error = !in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes);
```

Alternatively, the [`finfo` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) are great, if your server supports them.

Comment: I think this extensions are not enabled on my shared host : `extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll`

Comment: Is exif_imagetype unspoofable?

Comment: @assensi You might want to read up on what the different fields in `$_FILES` mean: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php. `tmp_name` is correct.

Comment: @decese - Is there a good method for getting the image type of an image stored in an in-mem string variable?  Loading user profile pics from MSGraph or retrieving them as a varbinary from SQL server, I get the image as a "string", but need to be able to set mime-types and send HTTP headers for browsers.
 
`$photoData = MSGraph::getUserProfilePic($username);
$photoType = SomeMagicMaetadataFunction($photoData);`

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated, as otherwise I'll need to binhex, learn some file formats and write a function to try parsing "manually" for my key cases.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to @deceze, you may also [finfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) to check the MIME-type of non-image-files:

```
$finfo = new finfo();
$fileMimeType = $finfo->file($path . $filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure you could check if it's an image with exif, but a better way I think is to do with finfo like this:

```
$allowed_types = array ( 'application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' );
$fileInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$detected_type = finfo_file( $fileInfo, $_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'] );
if ( !in_array($detected_type, $allowed_types) ) {
    die ( 'Please upload a pdf or an image ' );
}
finfo_close( $fileInfo );
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way in my opinion is first to use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) followed by [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

```
    $size = getimagesize($filename);
    if ($size === false) {
        throw new Exception("{$filename}: Invalid image.");
    }
    if ($size[0] > 2500 || $size[1] > 2500) {
        throw new Exception("{$filename}: Image too large.");
    }

    if (!$img = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename))) {
        throw new Exception("{$filename}: Invalid image content.");
    }
```

Checking by `getimagesize()` prevents some DoS attacks, because we don't have to try to `imagecreatefromstring()` from every file provided by the user, either non-image file or file too big. Unfortunately, according to [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#refsect1-function.getimagesize-description) cannot be relied on for checking image type content.

The `imagecreatefromstring()` finally tries to open the file as an image - if is succeeds - we have an image.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple, one line script that I use often.

```
$image = "/var/www/Core/temp/image.jpg";
$isImage = explode("/", mime_content_type())[0] == "image";
```

Basically I am using mime_content_type() to get something like "image/jpg" and then exploding it by "/" and checking against the first element of the array to see if it says "image".

I hope it works!

Comment: See also `dirname($x)` instead of `explode("/", $x)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.5 I use this function for getting file type and check if image:

```
function getFileType( $file ) {
    return image_type_to_mime_type( exif_imagetype( $file ) );
}

// Get file type
$file_type = getFileType( 'path/to/images/test.png' );
echo $file_type;
// Prints image/png
// 1. All images have mime type starting with "image"
// 2. No other non-image mime types contain string "image" in it
```

Then you could do:

```
if ( strpos( $filetype, 'image' ) !== false ) {
    // This is an image 
}
```

Complete list of mime types: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Answer (score 0):

That last line is close. You can use:
`if (mime_content_type($_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']) == "image/gif"){...`

In the case I'm currently working on, my `$_FILES..['type']` reports itself as "text/csv", while both `mime_content_type()` and `finfo()` (suggested by others) report "text/plain.". As @deceze points out, `$_FILES..['type']` is only useful to know what type a client thinks a file is.

Answer (score -2):

you can try this

```
$file_extension = explode('.',$file['name']);
$file_extension = strtolower(end($file_extension));
$accepted_formate = array('jpeg','jpg','png');
if(in_array($file_extension,$accepted_formate)) {           
  echo "This is jpeg/jpg/png file";
} else {
  echo $file_extension.' This is file not allowed !!';
}
```

Comment: This is checking a file extension, not the MIME content type.

Answer (score -6):

**WARNING**: the following answer does not actually check the file type. It only checks the name. It is **not suitable** for actual security purposes.

**EDIT: Don't Use this method** as it serves no security check. I am leaving this answer here so that no one makes the same mistake like me by trying this.

---

I tried the following and it worked for me:

```
$allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg', 'pdf');
$filename = $_FILES['input_tag_name']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

[Source link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456113/php-check-file-extension-in-upload-form)

Comment: **WARNING! This checks absolutely nothing!** All it does is check if the extension is in your allowed array. If you rename `myVirus.exe` to `myVirus.jpg` it would get through your function just fine. Obviously that is **NOT** what you want...

Comment: This is highly dangerous.... Avoid and never use it for serious file-checking-matters