# Secure image upload PHP

Tags: php, image, security, file-upload, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Security threats with uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads)

I've been searching for a good script/tutorial for secure image upload, but whatever I find, reading the comments there seem to be issues with the script as far as security is concerned. So I tried to compose my on script. I would like to ask for any security suggestions on this.

```
//create arrays from allowed extensions and types
$allowed_exts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
$allowed_types = array("image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif");

//extract extension from uploaded file
$ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES["image"]["name"], strrpos($_FILES["image"]["name"], ".") + 1));
```

I first check if the extension is one of the allowed

```
 if(in_array($ext, $allowed_exts) === false){
    echo "Only .jpg, .png, .gif allowed";
    }
```

Then check if the type is one of the allowed

```
 elseif(in_array($_FILES["image"]["type"], $allowed_types) === false){
    echo "Only .jpg, .png, .gif allowed";
    }
```

Then check the filesize

```
elseif($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 2100000){
    echo "File is too big";
}
```

Now use getimagesize to check for dimensions

```
   elseif(!getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])){ 
    echo "File is not an image";
    } else {
```

I create a random file name

```
$filename = mt_rand(1000,99999)."_".$_POST['p_id'].".jpg";
```

If this is all fine, I create a thumb using GD. In short (incase its a jpeg):

```
a. imagecreatefromjpeg -> from uploaded file
b. imagecreatetruecolor -> with desired thumbnail dimensions
c. imagecopyresampled -> modify the image created under a.
d. imagejpeg -> save image to destination
```

So, as I've read this should eliminate most problems that come with the image, but I m sure I missed something important.

The directory I write the files to has 755 permission, but I think I have to make more restrictions on the directory by putting a .htaccess in the folder? What should be in there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Security threats with uploads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads) and [uploaded file type check by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php)

Comment: Ive read many of these kind of posts, but none of them is giving me a conclusive answer on how to let users upload images securely.

Answer (score 0):

I Made a string clean up script a while back, i think it might help. remember to clean up all your $_POST items like this:

```
//CLEAN-UP FUNCTIONS
function ms($v) {
     $v = str_replace("<br />","",$v); 
     $v = str_replace(" ","-",$v); 

     // Replace UTF-8 characters.
     $v = str_replace(
        array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6"),
        array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),$v);

     // Replace their Windows-1252 equivalents.
     $v = str_replace(
        array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133)),
        array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),$v);
     // Finalize                    
     $v = htmlspecialchars($v, ENT_QUOTES);
     //$v = nl2br($v);
     return $v;
}
```

Usage:

```
$id = ms($_POST['p_id']);
```