# php and ajax image upload validation

Tags: javascript, php, validation

How to create a php image uploader with file system in which i could preview the thumb of image before uploading it to server and also validate the file before uploading.

I am using following code for image manipulation and saving.

**HTML code:**

```
<form id="imageform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action='upload.php'>
    <div id='imageloadstatus' style='display:none'><img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/></div>
    <div id='imageloadbutton'>
        <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
    </div>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

// include ImageManipulator class
require_once('ImageManipulator.php');

if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] . "<br />";
} else {
    // array of valid extensions
    $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
    // get extension of the uploaded file
    $fileExtension = strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], ".");
    // check if file Extension is on the list of allowed ones
    if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {
        $newNamePrefix = 'Thumb' . '_';
        $newNamePrefix1 = 'Highdef' . '_';
        $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        $manipulator1 = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        // resizing to 200x200
        $newImage = $manipulator->resample(200, 200);
        $newImage1 = $manipulator1->resample(1024, 768);
        // saving file to uploads folder
        $manipulator->save('uploads/thumbs/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['fileToUpload'] ['name']);
        $manipulator1->save('uploads/highDef/' . $newNamePrefix1 . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
        echo 'Done ...';
        $folder = 'uploads/thumbs/';
        $filetype = '*.*';
        $files = glob($folder . $filetype);
        $count = count($files);
        echo '<table>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            echo '<tr><td>';
            echo '<a name="' . $i . '" href="#' . $i . '"><img src="' . $files[$i] . '" /></a>';
            echo substr($files[$i], strlen($folder), strpos($files[$i], '.') - strlen($folder));
            echo '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo 'You must upload an image...';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: to preview an image before it is uploaded then you will need to use the HTML5 file api. Tons of examples on the web but this one, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ , covers various uses.

Comment: Please view this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php

Comment: well the thing is we cannot create thumb(resizing) of that file using html without compromising the image.