# PHP file upload not working for mp4

Tags: php, file-upload, mp4

I am checking if the file is of mp4 format once a user submits the form, this does not work for me:

```
if(!($_FILES["videoFile"]["type"] == "video/mp4"))
{
   // error handling
}
```

The file type works for other file types such as png/jpg ect but not for mp4.

```
echo $_FILES["videoFile"]["type"] = [tmp_name] 
echo $_FILES["videoFile"]["name"] = movie_300.mp4
```

when I print out the array of files i get:

```
Array ( [videoFile] => Array ( [name] => movie_300.mp4 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ))
```

Why is my file type [tmp_name] when uploading mp4s?

Comment: Have you checked the value of $_FILES["videoFile"]["type"]?

Comment: can you put the out put of <?php print_r($_FILES); ?> on submit.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6755263/258674

Comment: You could also check your input's name `videoFile` is not the same as `videofile`. Also try a "positive" approach `if($_FILES["videoFile"]["type"] == "video/mp4"){...} else{...}`

Comment: It's not a case sensitivity issue fred.
@guru i printed out the results and the type is [tmp_name]

Comment: @dev-null-dweller can i use "exif_imagetype" for video formats?

Comment: _Why is my file type [tmp_name] when uploading mp4s?_ It's not, it's empty, as is `[type]`, the uploaded file size is also 0. `[error] => 1` Indicates that you have an error uploading the file, try dumping `$_FILES["videoFile"]["error"]` to see what it is.

Comment: @TheBlueDog when I print `$_FILES["videoFile"]["error"]` it outputs: 1.

Is there a proper way to dump the error data or display the message associated with 1? I am quite new to PHP

Comment: You have an error on file upload. May be server limited by file size. Or write permission issue on server.

Comment: I sure have. I just made a 1second mp4 and it works. Thanks for helping me, most people on this site have no patience for new users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've exceeded your maximum file upload size, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

You can increase this using the following directive at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M'); // set max size to 10M (or whatever)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat little function.

http://subinsb.com/php-find-file-mime-type

I'd be careful with your validation because I'm pretty sure mimes can be spoofed fairly easily. Maybe someone with more security experience can weigh in on that subject. I'd at least perform a few other checks.

Cheers!