# Multiple file upload with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to uplod multiple files through ajax but I can't figure out how I can grab the files in PHP. Can anyone help me? Thank you!
Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" name="file"/>
</form>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#file").change(function(){

        var src=$("#file").val();
        if(src!="")
        {
            formdata= new FormData();  // initialize formdata
            var numfiles=this.files.length;  // number of files
            var i, file, progress, size;
            for(i=0;i<numfiles;i++)
            {
                file = this.files[i];
                size = this.files[i].size;
                name = this.files[i].name;
                if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/))  // Verify image file or not
                {
                    if((Math.round(size))<=(1024*1024)) //Limited size 1 MB
                    {
                        var reader = new FileReader();  // initialize filereader
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);  // read image file to display before upload
                        $("#preview").show();
                        $('#preview').html("");
                        reader.onloadend = function(e){
                            var image = $('<img>').attr('src',e.target.result);
                            $(image).appendTo('#preview');
                        };
                        formdata.append("file[]", file);  // adding file to formdata
                        console.log(formdata);
                        if(i==(numfiles-1))
                        {
                            $("#info").html("wait a moment to complete upload");
                            $.ajax({

                                url: _url + "?module=ProductManagement&action=multiplePhotoUpload",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: formdata,
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                success: function(res){
                                    if(res!="0")
                                        $("#info").html("Successfully Uploaded");
                                    else
                                        $("#info").html("Error in upload. Retry");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#info").html(name+"Size limit exceeded");
                        $("#preview").hide();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#info").html(name+"Not image file");
                    $("#preview").hide();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $("#info").html("Select an image file");
            $("#preview").hide();
            return;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

And in PHP I get $_POST and $_FILES as an empty array;
Only if I do file_get_contents("php://input"); I get something like

```
-----------------------------89254151319921744961145854436
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="dasha.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG

���
IHDR��Ò��¾���gÇº¨���    pHYs��������tIMEÞ/§ýZ�� �IDATxÚìw`EÆgv¯¥B-4 ½Ò»tBU©)"¶+*"( E¥J7ôÞ;Ò¤W©¡&puwçûce³WR¸ èóûrw»³ï}fö
```

But I can't figure out how to proceed from here.

I am using Jquery 1.3.2 maybe this is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: try to use name as a array. like file[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the answer, but I can't add a comment yet.

I would recommend not checking the file type in javascript, it is easily bypassed. I prefer to scrutinise the file in PHP before allowing it to be uploaded to a server.

e.g.

This answer taken from another question ([uploaded file type check by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6755192/1720515)), gives you an idea:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755263/1720515

```
<?php
$allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
$detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']);
$error = !in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes);
?>
```

You can read the documentation on the `exif_imagetype()` function **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)**.

**Could you post your PHP code please?** And I will update my answer if I have anything to add.

**UPDATE:**

**NOTE:** The 'multiple' attribute (`multiple="multiple"`) cannot be used with an `<input type='file' />` field. Multiple `<input type='file' />` fields will have to be used in the form, naming each field the same with `[]` added to the end to make sure that the contents of each field are added to an array, and do not overwrite each other when the form is posted.

e.g.

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input type="file" id="file_0" name="img_file[]" />
  <input type="file" id="file_1" name="img_file[]" />
  <input type="file" id="file_2" name="img_file[]" />
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the contents of any `<input type='file' />` fields will be added to the PHP `$_FILES` array. The files can then be referenced using `$_FILES['img_file'][*parameter*][*i*]`, where '*i*' is key associated with the file input and '*paramter*' is one of a number of parameters associated with each element of the `$_FILES` array:

e.g.

- `$_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'][0]` - when the form is submitted a temporary file is created on the server, this element contains the 'tmp_name' that is generated for the file.
- `$_FILES['img_file']['name'][0]` - contains the file name including the file extension.
- `$_FILES['img_file']['size'][0]` - contains the file size.

`$_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'][0]` can be used to preview the files before it is permanently uploaded to the server (looking at your code, this is a feature you want to include)

The file must then be moved to its permanent location on the server using PHP's [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function.

Here is some example code:

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'] as $file_key => $file_val) {
      /*
        ...perform checks on file here

        e.g. Check file size is within your desired limits,
             Check file type is an image before proceeding, etc.
      */

      $permanent_filename = $_FILES['img_file']['name'][$file_key];

      if (@move_uploaded_file($file_val, 'upload_dir/' . $permanent_filename)) {
        // Successful upload
      } else {
        // Catch any errors 
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Here are some links that may help with your understanding:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php
- http://www.sitepoint.com/handle-file-uploads-php/

Plus, some extra reading concerning the theory around securing file upload vulnerabilities:

- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Web_Application_Security_Guide/File_upload_vulnerabilities

Comment: About the PHP code I cant post any thing because I can't figure out how to grab the data and to process it only thing I have a input $file =  file_get_contents("php://input");
        print_r($file);

Comment: I am aware how to upload a file on the server but the main problem that i encounter is that I am trying to do that with ajax. At the moment a simple var_dump of the globals $_FILES and $_POST returns emppty. the only way I get something in return is by  using $file = file_get_contents("php://input"); but i dont know how to proceed from this. Thank you James for the answers!

Comment: So the PHP file that you are posting to (`_url + "?module=ProductManagement&action=multiplePhotoUpload"`) only contains `$file = file_get_contents("php://input"); print_r($file);`?

Comment: yes, and a simple var_dump shows in the console a string o characters like I showed above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ajax form` upload plugin 

 That's what i have found couple of days ago and implemented it this way
Ref : [LINK](https://github.com/malsup/form)

You PHP Code can be like this

`uploadimage.php`

```
    $response = array();
    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        /* Function for moving file to a location and get it's URL */
        $response[] = FileUploader::uploadImage($file);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

`JS Code`

```
      options = {
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    // Do some image loading
                },
                uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete)
                {
                    // Do some upload progresss
                },
                success: function()
                {
                    // After Success
                },
                complete: function(response)
                {
                    // Stop Loading
                },
                error: function()
                {

                }

            };

            $("#form").ajaxForm(options);
```

Now you can call any AJAX and submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider below code

**HTML**

```
   <input type="file" name="fileUpload" multiple>
```

**AJAX**

- first of all you have to get all the files which you choose in "input type file" like this.

  ```
          var file_data = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files;
          var form_data = new FormData();

          for(var i=0;i<file_data.length;i++)
          {

              form_data.append(file_data[i]['name'], file_data[i]);
          }
  ```
- then all your data is in formData object now you can send it to server(php) like this.

  ```
          $.ajax({
              url: 'upload.php', //your php action page name
              dataType: 'json', 
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              data: form_data,
              type: 'post',
              success: function (result) {
                // code you want to execute on success of ajax request
              },
              error: function (result) {
                //code you want to execute on failure of ajax request
              }
          });
  ```

  **PHP**

  ```
  <?php

  foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
  {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' .$_FILES[$key]['name']);

  }
  ```