# How to upload ONLY images in database

Tags: php, image

I want to upload ONLY pictures , in the database using php. 
What I tried is,

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Upload'])) {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("iis", $con);
    $image = $_FILES["product_image"]["name"];
    $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["product_image"]["type"]);
    if (substr($imageType, 0, 5) == "image") {
        if (!file_exists("product_images")) {
            mkdir("product_images");
        }

        if ($_FILES["product_image"]["error"] > 0) {
            $error = "ERROR Return Code :" . $_FILES["product_image"]["error"] . "<br />";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["product_image"]["tmp_name"], "product_images/" . $_FILES["product_image"]["name"]);
        }
    }

    $UserName = $_SESSION['id'];
    $product_image = ("product_images/" . $_FILES["product_image"]["name"]);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `feedbackzxc` VALUES ('', '$UserName', '$product_image')");
    echo "Image Uploaded!";
} else {
    echo "Only images are allowed";
}

?>
```

But when I upload a file other than images it doesn't show the error message. How can I make it show error message if a file other than an image is uploaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [uploaded file type check by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php)

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` block where the message **Only images are allowed** is shown must be located after the `if` block that check this: `substr($imageType,0,5) == "image"`

```
if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image"){
    if(!file_exists("product_images"))
    {
        mkdir("product_images");
    }
    if($_FILES["product_image"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        $error = "ERROR Return Code :" . $_FILES["product_image"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    { 

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["product_image"]["tmp_name"], "product_images/". 
        $_FILES["product_image"]["name"]);  
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Only images are allowed";
}
```