# Validation for file upload

Tags: validation, file-upload, input

Am allowing user to upload multiple image **Now my problem is How do i find its only a image or it contains some hack code**

**Do i need to make a validator or How can i find ??**

Because there are many method to hack uploading by image

How do i prevent or protect my website hacking from file upload process, I allow use *File input 'accept' attribute*

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*"></label></p>
```

Will this protect ,,

Can somebody help me to make client-side and server-side validation

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not secure.

Instead, use the server-side PHP function [`exif_imagetype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) to check if it is an image. See the code below:

```
$allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
$detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']);
$error = !in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes);
```

Find more information here: [uploaded file type check by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php). Alternately, you could use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

Comment: but i would like to make server-side and client-side validation

Answer (score 0):

try this simple client side validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"];

function Validate(oForm) {
    var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oInput.type == "file") {
            var sFileName = oInput.value;
            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                var blnValid = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                        blnValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!blnValid) {
                    alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
```

Form should look like this:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
```

and for server side use

```
if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif', '.jpg', '.png'))) {
            $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
        }
```