# How to give validation rules in Yii to upload all file other then (.php, aspx, .cs etc)

Tags: php, yii, rules

```
return array(
  array('speech', 'required'),
  array('speech,document,speech_on,created_on, updated_on,inactive','safe')
  array('document','file','restrict','types'=>'.php,.aspx,.cs', 'maxSize'=>1024*1024*2,'tooLarge'=>'Size should be less then 2MB','on'=>'upload'),      
);
```

How can restrict these file to upload,

Comment: what do you exactly need ? with that rule you have already got it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the coding, what I want:

Added custom rule like this

```
array('document_path', 'docTypeRule','param'=>array('file'=>$documentName,'restrict'=>array('cs','php','aspx'))),


public function docTypeRule($attribute,$params)
{
    $extn = strtolower(pathinfo($params['param']['file'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    //Put
    if(in_array($extn, $params['param']['restrict'])){
      $this->addError($attribute, 'Invalid file type, .'.$extn.' file not allowed!');
    }
}
```

Please comment if anything wrong, but this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

add a custom rule like this:

```
array('document', 'docTypeRuleValidator'),
```

then create that custom validation rule inside `components/validators` with the name `docTypeRuleValidator` as:

```
class DocTypeRuleValidator extends CValidator
{
    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
        yii::trace($attribute, __METHOD__);
        yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($_FILES), __METHOD__);

        if(in_array($_FILES['ModHwTM']['type']['imageUploaded'], array('image/jpg')))
        {
            $this->addError($model, $attribute, 'Not appropiate type!');
        }
    }
}
```

the trick here is to find the exact parameter of the Files array you want to use to validate type, following php zend certification specs is not enough to use Files, cause it could be manipulated by the user so this is a first validation ... if it pass then you should to check the temp file you have uploaded to make sure it is the type you support, but it is a great start i think.

For example  i have made a test an the $_files array returns:

```
array
(
        'ModHwTM' => array
        (
                'name' => array
                (
                        'imageUploaded' => 'crude_widnows.jpg'
                )
                'type' => array
                (
                        'imageUploaded' => 'image/jpeg'
                )
                'tmp_name' => array
                (
                        'imageUploaded' => '/tmp/phpcYm2Vo'
                )
                'error' => array
                (
                        'imageUploaded' => 0
                )
                'size' => array
                (
                        'imageUploaded' => 6527
                )
        )
)
```

please read: [how $files works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php)

you could use this example to create your own custom validator to check the temp file
Please add your comments...

Comment: `$attribute['type']` not return the selected file extension.

Comment: @UmashankarSaw my mistake , i gthink should be $attribute['userfile']['name'] already fixed that

Comment: @UmashankarSaw you could also vardump in the trace the attribute value to make sure what attribute is returning and make better my validator ...

Comment: When I dump the variable using var_dump() I got this `string 'document' (length=8)`, $attribute not come as array.

Comment: @UmashankarSaw I hope this helps you out .