# cURL error Couldn't resolve host 'Bearer'

Tags: curl

I'm trying to connect to the Adobe Analytics found [here](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-live-stream/data-requests)

I've managed to generate an auth token using the below request:

> curl -i -v "https://api.omniture.com/token" -u 'my-user' -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

I then copy the whole object thats returned which looks something like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "some-really-long-access-token",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "scope": "livestream",
  "success": true
}
```

and paste it into the following cURL:

> curl --location --compressed --header “Authorization: Bearer [{"access_token":"some-really-long-access-token","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"bearer","scope":"livestream","success":true}]” [https://livestream.adobe.net/api/1/stream/myendpoint]

The error i'm getting is:

```
Couldn't resolve host 'Bearer'
```

I'm fairly new to cURL so not sure if there is an obvious error here? Will most likely be down to the way i'm sending the data over...

**EDIT**

After the answer written below this is the error message i'm getting:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Bearer'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'some-really-long-auth-key
invalid authorization header
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check uploaded file type in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/how-to-check-uploaded-file-type-in-php)

Comment: Had a similar problem in windows cmd, but WSL2 ran it with no issues.

Answer (score 11):

**Okay, the part you need to pass in the header** is the `"some-really-long-access-token"`

Example:

```
curl --compressed --header "Authorization: Bearer some-really-long-access-token" "https://livestream.adobe.net/api/1/stream/myendpoint"
```

So just pay attention to the encoding on the `"`.

- `“` is not the same as `"`
- When copying / pasting from HTML, Rich text, or something other than a code block, it's best to check this

**Edit:**

Your question is tagged `php`, but your examples are using the command line, therefore, ensure your command is formatted using the following points:

## First and foremost:

- The examples on the [Adobe Developer Connection](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-live-stream/data-requests) page also showing arguments inside [square brackets], for example:

[image]

## Other general things to check:

- A header is passed like this:  `-H "Header-name: Header-Value"`

  - Therefore, if my access token was `29035-97v657zyr8qk966y143k2v0p365460xbd1pvk9p6`
    Then my header arguments would be this:

    - `-H "Authorization: Bearer 29035-97v657zyr8qk966y143k2v0p365460xbd1pvk9p6"`
- You can explicitly specify the url to `cURL` using `--url`.  I don't usually do this because it shouldn't be necessary if everything is correct, but it may help refine the error message.

  - So my URL arguments would be this:

    - `--url "https://livestream.adobe.net/api/1/stream/myendpoint"`
- Be sure as described above **NOT** to use LEFT AND RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK `“` and `”`, but the standard `"` found on the computer keyboard.  The standard `"` **is what the shell uses to contain arguments**

Comment: I tried what you said but still getting an error. See my edited question above for the error im getting

Comment: Can you post in your edit the *exact* command (you can change your endpoint to just /endpoint and your access token to just access-token)

Comment: @BenLiger I've modified my answer to be more helpful - But I will need to modify it again to be more generic and benefit the rest of the community once your problem is resolved, so please post back here your results asap

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but now i'm getting this error: 'token' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @BenLiger You clearly have syntax errors and shell quoting issues.  Please see my edited example, particularly the section "First and foremost" to make absolutely sure you fix that up first.   What happens when you copy and paste my very first dummy example (on the third line of my answer), into the shell.  It should say "401 unauthorized" and eventually say "internal error".  Please confirm this.