# I'm looking for a script to restrict file extension type and size on my contact form attachment?

Tags: php

This is the script I am currently trying to us:

```
$allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg'); // Allowed file extensions
$filename = $_FILES['video_file']['image'];//File name 
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// File path information
//if file extension is equal to allowed file extensions 
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

This however does not work and just stops the form submitting; otherwise the form sends the attachment with no problem.

Comment: How do you expect to get a filename from `$_FILES['video_file']['image']` ?

Comment: You would have better luck checking for image upload with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755263/2960971

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the file *array* to `pathinfo()` instead of the file *name*. You should do:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['your_file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

You could debug using `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_FILES['file'], true) . '</pre>';` to see how `$_FILES` handle uploads. Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => filename.ext        // <-- This is what you want to give to pathinfo()
    [type] => type
    [tmp_name] => tmp\path.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 33942
)
```